# Android - Bluetooth - Crash at the end of write

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, inputstream

I am new to android, and I'm basically sending a simple byte stream between two devices.

It seems by adding the additional activity (a confirmation button on a second layout) I have introduced some underlying complexity, and I can't pin-point why the crash AFTER the transmission. The message is transmitted on the input stream, and received on the output stream, but the logs seem to indicate a broken pipe, despite a transmission occurring.

I have tried to ensure that the java class for the 'confirm page' inherits the BT capability from the 'main'.

I suspect the error is in MainActivity, and it is upon returning from the confirmation screen that this error happens.

*What happens is that I have a new activity, with a corresponding button, to confirm the start process. Once confirmed, the BT should send a start signal, and return to the main layout

This is where I suspect the error is localized.

**MainActivity class**

```
public void OnStartClick(View view) {


    Intent GetStartConfirmation = new Intent(this, StartConfirm.class);

    final int res = 99; // can use as a signal for another time

    startActivityForResult(GetStartConfirmation, res);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    startPaintbot = resultCode;

    updateUi(resultCode);
}
private void updateUi(int res)
{
    if(res == 1) {
        //this should all be done on a result of '1'
        char data[] = {'s', 't', 'a', 'r', 't', 'u', 'p'};
        String str = new String(data);
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
    }
    else if (res == 0)
    {
        char data[] = {'s', 'u', 'p','p'};
        String str = new String(data);
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
    }
    else
    {
        char data[] = {'s', 'y', 'w','a'};
        String str = new String(data);
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
        mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
    }
}
```

**StartConfirm class**

```
public class StartConfirm extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.start_confirm_layout);

    Intent activityStartHome = getIntent();

}



public void OnStartConfirmation(View view) {
    // Vid 5, Derek
    Intent toStart = new Intent();

    // this is where the difficulties lie, the intents.

    setResult(1, toStart);

    finish(); // eventually will need to add something to these two intents
}

public void OnNoStartConfirmation(View view) {

    Intent DoNotStart = new Intent();

    setResult(0, DoNotStart);
    //Do not want canceled, indicates there was a failure on the button

    finish();
}
}
```

The output log is as follows:

```
04-12 02:59:33.379 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
write: Writing to outputstream: startup

04-12 02:59:33.379 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface D/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Write Called.
write: Writing to outputstream: startup
04-12 02:59:33.379 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface E/BluetoothConnectionServ: write: Error writing to output stream. Broken pipe
04-12 02:59:33.449 15665-15680/com.example.piotr.userinterface D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x9f355d80 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9f42c370
04-12 02:59:33.459 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8eaf228 time:88717553
04-12 02:59:33.699 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface D/MainActivity: onDestroy: called.
04-12 02:59:33.699 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-12 02:59:33.699 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.piotr.userinterface, PID: 15665
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.piotr.userinterface/com.example.piotr.userinterface.StartConfirm}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.piotr.userinterface.MainActivity$1@dadacf9
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5061)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:221)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1853)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.piotr.userinterface.MainActivity$1@dadacf9
    at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:878)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1283)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:601)
    at com.example.piotr.userinterface.MainActivity.onDestroy(MainActivity.java:217)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7102)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:221) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1853) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
04-12 02:59:36.049 15665-15665/com.example.piotr.userinterface I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 15665 SIG: 9
```

Apologies if that is disgusting

https://github.com/PK-GH/PB/tree/PeteInWonderland/app/src/main/java/com/example/piotr/userinterface

Comment: can you provide the crash log

Answer (score 0):

Your device which receiving data is disconected with device sending that's why broken pipe appered.
That appere only when 1 side of connection is broken can't know which but in this case i thing is receiver becouse of 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.example.piotr.userinterface/com.example.piotr.userinterface.StartConfirm}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.example.piotr.userinterface.MainActivity$1@dadacf9`

My advice check connection is it connected before and if yes debug step by step and find place where disconecting

Comment: Thanks, looking into it. The only thing that's strange is when I check the logcat and see that the message has actually been received on the receiver side. Still isolating the problem.